# Ignore a MySQL query if no record(s) found

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a list of soccer fixtures for the year. Fixtures are contested on most weekends - but, notably, not all.

The website currently displays fixtures in this style/format, with separate MySQL statements running for each weekend:

**Weekend 1**

*Team A vs Team B*

*Team C vs Team D*

**Weekend 2**

*No Fixtures*

**Weekend 3**

*Team B vs Team D*

*Team C v Team A*

**Weekend 4**

*No Fixtures*

How can I get a MySQL statement to completely ignore any dates that do not have any fixtures? That is to say, in the above example, I would not want **Weekends 2 or 4** to show at all.

However, should a fixture be unexpectedly rearranged to those weekends, I *WOULD* want it to show. Currently, I am removing/inserting new MySQL statements when such rearrangements occur, which is time consuming.

It would be less work for me if I could avoid this. Thanks in advance for any advice!

```
<?php
$servername = "#";
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$dbname = "#";
    
            
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "
SELECT * 
FROM fixtures
WHERE rel_date 
BETWEEN '2023-09-02' AND '2023-09-03' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


echo "<h3>Weekend 2</h3>";              

                    
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    
                
echo "<div class='fixture-strip'>";
echo "" .$row["fixtures"]. "";
echo "</div>";
                
}

} else {
echo "<p>No fixtures on this date</p>";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

| rel_date | fixtures |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-09 | Team A vs Team B |
| 2023-03-09 | Team C vs Team D |
| 2023-03-17 | Team B vs Team D |
| 2023-03-17 | Team C vs Team A |
| 2023-10-01 | Team D vs Team A |
| 2023-10-01 | Team B vs Team C |

Comment: | rel_date | fixtures |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2023-03-09    | Team A vs Team B    |
| 2023-03-09    | Team C vs Team D    |
| 2023-03-17     | Team B vs Team D    |
| 2023-03-17     | Team C vs Team A    |
| 2023-10-01     | Team D vs Team A    |
| 2023-10-01     | Team B vs Team C    |



etc etc

I hope the above is the information you were needing, apologies I'm still trying to get used to asking questions using the Stackoverflow forms!

Thanks again

Comment: So you are *actually* asking  *how to move `echo "<h3>Weekend 2</h3>";` inside the `if` condition so it won't show, and remove the `else` part so it won't display on empty weekends?* You should probably spend more time learning the logic of your code

Comment: I guess that's exactly what I am asking. Thank you for putting it slightly more succinctly than I had originally :)

You're right... maybe I probably should spend more time learning the logic of my code.... at the same time, maybe you should probably spend more time reading the first sentence of the question?  

I'm new to this and I'm trying to learn. I've gotten stuck and I'm looking for some advice or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: So this is *not enough* advice yet? A literal instruction telling what you should do is still not clear? Is this code written by you? Do you actually understand what does *"move `echo "<h3>Weekend 2</h3>";` inside the `if` condition"* mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(rel_date), WEEK(rel_date, 1)) AS weekend_no
FROM fixtures
WHERE rel_date BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2024-03-17'
ORDER BY rel_date;
```

to retrieve all the fixtures for the time period you are interested in. The use of [DENSE_RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) is giving us the weekend number. This can then be used in your loop to decide whether to display  your weekend header or not:

```php
<?php
$servername = '#';
$username = '#';
$password = '#';
$dbname = '#';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

// Create connection
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset($charset);
$conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);

$sql = <<<'SQL'
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(rel_date), WEEK(rel_date, 1)) AS weekend_no
    FROM fixtures
    WHERE rel_date BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2024-03-17'
    ORDER BY rel_date;
    SQL;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$prev_weekend = null;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($prev_weekend != $row['weekend_no']) {
        echo "<h3>Weekend {$row['weekend_no']}</h3>";
        $prev_weekend = $row['weekend_no'];
    }

    echo "<div class='fixture-strip'>{$row['fixtures']}</div>";

}
```

If the "weekend number" is the count from the first weekend of the season you could use something like:

```sql
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, '2023-09-30', rel_date) + 1 AS weekend_no
FROM fixtures
WHERE rel_date BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2024-03-17';
```

where `'2023-09-30'` represents the first Saturday of the season. This could be stored in a `seasons` table with the id of the season added to your `fixtures` table.

You should read [Mysqli tutorial (how to use it properly)](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli) before going any further.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ixoStzxt)

Comment: Sadly, you you completely missed the point. It is not the week number which is decided upon, whether to show it

Comment: That's a common task which you describe, but the actual question is much more silly :)

Comment: I definitely need to go and do something else for a few hours, as my head is clearly not _"in the game"_ ;-)

Comment: Wait. It should do too. What he wants is to hide the header if no evens on the weekend. And your code wouldn't show such weekends already.

Comment: But alas, it will break the numeration. I would rather calculate the number in PHP, based on the actual weeknumber. Or whatever algorithm they are using

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I don't get the meaning of the "weekend number". I was trying to avoid OP's static numbering. If we knew how the "weekend number" was defined we could make it dynamic.

Comment: Well we can be simply seed it with like $start = "2023-08-26", get the weeknumber for this date and get the diff which is 34. Now the relative weeknumber is the absolute weeknumber - 34. Until January of course